# Не получается проверить массив

Tags: массивы, pascal

Мне необходимо проверить, лежит ли в массиве число = 3.75. Затем вывести индекс элемента массива, в котором лежит это число. 
Я написал код, который, вроде, должен решать проблему, но он не делает этого. В чем может быть его проблема?

Код:

```
const size = 6;
var number: real;
    mas: array [1..size] of real;
    counter: integer;
begin
    counter := 1;
    repeat
      write('Введите ',counter,' число > ');
      readln(number);
      counter += 1;
    until counter > 6;

    writeln('Начинаю просматривать массив.........................=)');
    counter := 0;

    for var i := 1 to 6 do
      begin
      if mas[i] = 3.75 then
        begin
        writeln('Число под номером ',i,' = 3.75');
        counter += 1;
        end;
      end;

      if counter = 0 then
        writeln('Среди введенных чисел, числа 3.75 - нет. Дасвиданья.');
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эм.  Вы шесть раз считываете `number` вместо заполнения
массива.